# Afxdaoterm when to use

Tags: c++, database, mfc, dao

I have a dao database which is init in the separate dal i.e all the ado and dao is there is seprate dll.

I had created a dll for some purpose and used this dll and to init dabase and it worked.

I had created a ocx and init this database it didn't worked I tried calling in exit instance  afxdaoterm.

My doubt is where we have to call afxdaoterm ? Iam initing this database in lot of places ..can we have call afxdaoterm I'n destuctor ..it's crashing some times ..

Where we have to call afxdaoterm ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call AfxDaoTerm at all!

When AfxDaoInit is called, a state in the CWinApp is set and when CWinApp:ExitInstance is called than AfxDaoTerm is called.

So mainly the question is, what kind of DLL are you using. Regular DLLs or extension DLLs?

In Regular DLLs there is a CWinApp object per DLL. For extension DLLs the CWinApp object is shared from the main process.

Even for a regular DLL AfxDaoTerm is called, Problems might arise on regular DLLs when AfxDaoInit and AfxDaoTerm may be called from different threads. Check this and try to prevent this.

Because regular DLLs use DllMain to start InitInstance and ExitInstance. there should be some code to isolate the Dao stuff in separate Init and Uninit Functions called from the using process.

Comment: in ocx if where not calling afxdaoterm its giving abort error ..but if i call in exit instance its looping

Comment: Remember that ExitInstance in a DLL is called from DllMain. You are not allowed to call such functions from DllMain. EVen doing it in InitInstance will be a problem. A DLL is a code container, not a process or a thread. A DLL will not behave as a thread or process... separate the Init and Uninit functions and let them be called from the EXE from the point you need.